# Apple Mac-o-Linker (id) error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, linker

I have deleted some .h and .m libraries which were not required in my project and now i am getting this error:

```
          Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-   gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1



          Ld /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DMFoundation-ecvyqffegvbtxxaoehzocbrnpinw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DMF.app/DMF normal i386
```

I am stuck with it. I shutdown my system. I am even getting the same error in my backup project in which those libraries exists :(.
Any Guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clean all targets and find what files are in red color in your project.Delete those things.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your Xcode organizer, choose project and click on delete derived data of the project. It can be solution for your problem